# While multiple condition with date in R

Tags: r

i want to have a past-2-days condition in while statement, so i write in this form:

```
while (xxx$mdate >= Sys.Date()-2 && xxx$mdate < Sys.Date()) {}
```

*mdate in date and time.

when i use single condition without AND, it works but it doesn't work with AND.

Comment: Could you supply a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: `while` expects a single logical value. Try `&` instead of `&&`

Answer (score 0):

You should contemplate the difference between the conventional vectorised and `&` the early stopping variant `&&`

```
(a1 <- c(FALSE,TRUE,FALSE))
(b2 <- rep(TRUE,3))

a1 & b2 
a1 && b2
```

Also while loops, are useful in R in a rare set of circumstances, its very unlikely that your code wouldn't be more elegant and robust to errors if you made use of R's vectorisation, and/or iteration via apply family or tidyverse purr map functions, as its been said; computers will need to loop, but why should you have to worry about the details ?

more links :

1)https://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html#for-loops-vs.-functionals

2)http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html